# PyQGIS set opacity problem.. I do not want for layer rendering but for styling

Tags: pyqgis, style, transparency-opacity

As you see in the picture, I used `setOpacity` method.

```
layer.setOpacity(0.5)
iface.mapCanvas().refreshAllLayers()
```

But my purpose was to change upper slide, not the below one. Is there a way for this?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The opacity slider above is about the symbol for the layer, not the layer itself. Therefore, you should use `layer.renderer().symbol().setOpacity(0.5)`.

[image]